# NextAuth signIn callbackUrl based on authenticated user role

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth, role-base-authorization

I made a single custom login page for all users, and I am trying to redirect the user to his dashboard based on his role. I am using next-auth credentials provider and I am flashing the user's role to the session.
Login page:

```js
const LoginPage: NextPage = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>();
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isValid },
  } = useForm<ILogin>({
    resolver: zodResolver(loginSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: ILogin) => {
    try {
      const res = await signIn(
        'admin-login',
        { ...values, redirect: false });
      console.log(res);
      if (!res || !res.ok) setStatus(res?.error);
      else if(res.ok)
         // redirect based on authenticated user role...
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error('SOME ERR: ', err);
      setStatus(err.message);
    }
  };
  return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          ...fields
        </form>
  );
};
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(
    ctx.req,
    ctx.res,
    authOptions
  );
  if (session?.user) {
    const destination = HOME_PAGES[(session as Session).user!.role];
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

Comment: What about this isn't working? Make sure the roles are set on the users' JWTs, get them server-side, and then redirect them depending on the role. Start using `console.log` like crazy to trace the issue.

Comment: the functionnality of getServerSideProps is properly working as it redirects if the user is authenticated. But I want to redirect after a successful login if the response from signIn is ok.

Comment: In the `if(res.ok){ ... }` block, have you tried retrieving the user's session with [`getSession`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession), checking the user's role and then redirecting to the appropriate route?